# Docker - connect from HOST to container

Tags: docker, jenkins, networking, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am using Docker for Windows with created bridge network:

- `"bridge":"none"` (daemon.json)
- `docker network create --subnet 192.168.23.1/24 --gateway 192.168.23.1 --driver bridge my-network`

... and container with Jenkins image.

When I configure connection between Jenkins (container) and Gitlab ("internet") everything is working fine. But when I am creating Webhook in Gitlab I have to enter URL of Jenkins. I was trying with `localhost` and IP obtained from **IPAddress** property:

```
"Networks": {
    "my-network": {
        "IPAMConfig": null,
        "Links": null,
        "Aliases": [
            "jenkins",
            "dff5dcb7c95a"
        ],
        "NetworkID": "xxx",
        "EndpointID": "yyy",
        "Gateway": "192.168.23.1",
        "IPAddress": "192.168.23.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 24,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "zzz",
        "DriverOpts": null
    }
}
```

.. but both options have been not working.

**Question**: How to determine correct URL?

How to connect from HOST to my container? Is it correct approach? What issues should I know to resolve following problems in the future?

**Thanks for help :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your Gitlab-instance also in a Docker-container you just need to add the Gitlab-container to the same Docker-network.

If your Gitlab-instance is really in the internet, you can not solve this with localhost or any local IP-adress. You need to:

- find out your public IP-adress, maybe use dynDNS to get a fix domain if you have a dynamic IP
- open a port on your router and configure your firewall
- open a port on your local windows firewall
- need to find out on which port jenkins is waiting for the webhooks from GitLab
- map this port to the docker-container by using 
  `--p <docker-internal-port>:<docker-external-port>`

If you would provide some more information about your network infrastruture, the answer could be clearer.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! :)